# Diferença entre SceneBuilder e Aplicação JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, layout, scenebuilder

Pessoal estou usando o Scene Builder 2.0 para fazer o Layout da minha aplicação JavaFX. Quando vejo a aplicação pelo Scene Builder está tudo ok, porém quando rodo a aplicação JavaFX a lateral não fica igual ao desenho do Scene Builder, ele fica com um espaço maior no lado direito, coloquei anexo um print de cada um para vocês verem a diferença. A primeira  é a imagem do aplicativo, a segunda do Scene Builder
[image: Imagem do Aplicativo]

[image: Imagem Scene Builder 2.0]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<TabPane fx:id="tabPane" prefHeight="558.0" prefWidth="628.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="br.com.grupor.controlepostal.viewController.CadastroDestinatarioViewController">
   <tabs>
      <Tab fx:id="tabLista" text="Destinatários">
         <content>
            <FlowPane prefHeight="506.0" prefWidth="618.0">
               <children>
                  <Label contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Filtrar Destinatário">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="textFiltrarDestinatario" onKeyReleased="#filtrarDestinatarioOnReleased" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="510.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <Label text="Destinatários Localizados">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <ComboBox fx:id="comboBoxLocalizados" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="473.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </ComboBox>
                  <FlowPane alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="624.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="btnNovo" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnNovoOnAction" text="Novo">
                           <FlowPane.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                           </FlowPane.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnAlterar" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnAlterarOnAction" text="Alterar">
                           <FlowPane.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                           </FlowPane.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnExcluir" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnExcluirOnAction" text="Excluir">
                           <FlowPane.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                           </FlowPane.margin>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </FlowPane>
                  <TableView fx:id="tableViewLista" onMouseClicked="#tableViewListaClicked" prefHeight="404.0" prefWidth="619.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </FlowPane>
         </content>
      </Tab>
      <Tab fx:id="tabCadastro" text="Cadastro">
         <content>
            <FlowPane prefHeight="529.0" prefWidth="592.0">
               <children>
                  <Label text="Destinatário">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="textDestinatario" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="547.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <ComboBox fx:id="comboBoxTipoPessoa" prefWidth="150.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </ComboBox>
                  <Label text="Documento">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="textDocumento">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <Label text="OBS">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="textObs" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="196.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <Label text="CEP">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="textCep" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="75.0" />
                  <Label text="Endereço">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="textEndereco" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="455.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <Label text="Complemento">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="textComplemento" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="214.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <Label text="Bairro">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="textBairro" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="269.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <Label text="Cidade">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="textCidade" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="482.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <Label text="Estado">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="textEstado" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="36.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <Label text="E-mail">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="textEmail" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="330.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <Label text="Contato">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="textContato" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="184.0">
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <FlowPane alignment="TOP_RIGHT" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="631.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="btnCancelar" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnCancelarOnAction" text="Cancelar">
                           <FlowPane.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                           </FlowPane.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="btnSalvar" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnSalvarOnAction" text="Salvar">
                           <FlowPane.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                           </FlowPane.margin>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                     <FlowPane.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </FlowPane.margin>
                  </FlowPane>
               </children>
            </FlowPane>
         </content>
      </Tab>
   </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

Comment: Pode adicionar o código do seu fxml?

Comment: pronto adicionei o fxml

Comment: Amigo dê uma olhada no XML do seu layout e vá modificando os valores , porque um arquivo gerado pelo SceneBuilder nem sempre é igual no preview .